# Porting python script from Win10 to Ubuntu (Audio, Networking)

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, audio, udp

I wrote an bit of Python that captures microphone input and send it to another machine on the same private network, then maps it to the speakers of the second machine.
https://github.com/Bencosterton/BCAN-AoIP
The app runs in two parts, Client and Receiver.

This was written in Windos10 and works great between Windows machines.

I've decided to test it on linux (transmitter part) and getting a lot of ALSA and JACK related errors.

OS: Ubunut 22.04LTS + UbuntuStudio extras - Running on Virtualbox, bridged network adaptor.
Virtualbox has been given access to host audio in/out.

After installing the UbuntoStudio ALSA and JACK drivers, there is no change.
Any suggestions what to tackle first and how?

Output on launch of python script;

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
/home/ben/Desktop/reciever.py:42: DeprecationWarning: setDaemon() is deprecated, set the daemon attribute instead
  udpThread .setDaemon(True)
/home/ben/Desktop/reciever.py:43: DeprecationWarning: setDaemon() is deprecated, set the daemon attribute instead
  AudioThread.setDaemon(True)
^[[1;2D^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/Desktop/reciever.py", line 46, in <module>
    udpThread .join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1096, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1116, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Script now works on UbutuStudio 22.04;

```
sudo apt install build-essential portaudio19-dev python3.10-dev

pip install pyaudio
```

Portaudio is needed before you can get pyaudio to run.

It still throws the ALSA errors, but the app runs.